# TextView within a TableLayout only centered after configuration change

Tags: android, android-layout, centering

Within my main.xml, I have a table that has 2 columns and 2 rows; one for latitude & longitude and their associated values. I want them to be centered within their columns, and from my readings it seemed the best way to do that is with layout_weight="1" and gravity="center". This did work *most* of the time, but since I have made changes elsewhere in the code, now none of the items in gps_layout are centered **unless** the configuration is changed, in this case when I change the orientation by rotating the phone.

I know that rotation causes the app to go through its lifecycle (also is there a shorthand for talking about that other than calling it rebirth?) but I cannot understand what is different about the app after the first run, except for its saved state ... which would not seem to have much effect on centering. Thanks! Sorry if I did not format this question correctly, I have been trolling SO for awhile but this is my first question.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/gps_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:id="@+id/lat_text"
        android:text="latitude: "
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"                
        />
        <TextView    
        android:id="@+id/lon_text"
        android:text="longitude: "
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    ...etc...
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Did you apply any theme/style that might cause this problem? Or what are the changes in code after which your layout started messing up? The layout you've posted is working (showing up) as expected.

Comment: i don't have any theme/style set up yet, i do have that TableLayout within a RelativeLayout within a ScrollView. as far as the changes to the code ... i was working on a number of other seemingly unrelated issues to my main java class that involved the gps being disabled so i could run the program faster for debugging purposes, when gps is disabled, the table gps_layout is invisible, so i dont know when this happened :( i would love to share the whole code with you but thats probably more effort than i can ask of someone.

Comment: If you can temporarily share it somewhere, would be great, i'd love to take a look at it (morning). Keep in mind that with your questions everybody is challenged who take the time to answer, and in most cases also learn something; so even if effort, thanks.

Comment: awesome! well im going to open a github account, ive seen a lot of code posted on there. let me know if there is a better place i should try or if it would be easier to just send you a public dropbox link of my whole project so that you can open it on your machine without copy & paste. otherwise, ill post the link to the code up here shortly.

Comment: alright i decided against github, here is the public link to my dropbox folder with all files inside. ignore the apk, it is outdated. also, apologies in advance if the code is weak childish, this is the first app i have written and i havent had a java course in years.

(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16042321/Marine%20Debris.zip)

again, thanks so much!!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i wanted to be thorough, but the wierd thing is, I couldn't reproduce the problem. I've tested (besides 3 avd configurations) on 2 different devices with diff. version, and the latitude/longitude columns were centered from the moment they appeared. Did I not understand right your issue?

Comment: haha and you see how frustrating this is for me. as soon as gps_layout appears, on my phone, the columns appear to be left justified, going home or having onPause called has no effect, but for some reason changing the configuration (in this case by rotating the phone) causes them to be aligned correctly. it doesn't seem to show up wrong on the emulator (but i rarely use that as its super slow) my phone is running cy 7.0.1 w/ android 2.3.3 but i dont see how that would have any impact. its not a big deal at all, just bizarre and annoying. thanks anyway, if i get it fixed ill let you know.

Comment: @rekaszeru i dont know why i didnt try this first. i set gps_layout so that it is always visible, and it starts out being centered properly, its only after the `TextView lat_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat_data); lat_view.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));` and associated lines for lon_view that it becomes left justified. i tried commenting out parts of that to see if it had an impact and it did the first time i commented it all out ... but now it isnt ...

Comment: that's really weird! I've just posted a 'try-other-layout' answer, since i cannot test on cy 7.0.1, and can't see the error either. Please post your answer too, if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't reproduce your error, I'd suggest you give a try to a different layout (with the same supposed resulting display aspect), like:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/gps_layout" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/acquire"
    android:visibility="invisible">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lat_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="latitude: " 
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lat_data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(lat goes here)" 
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lon_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="longitude: " android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lon_data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(lon goes here)" 
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully it will solve the problem on your cy 7.0.1.

**Update**
Some advises regarding your code:

In the `MyLocationListener` you shouldn't set every time the visibility of the two layout, this way it would be more effective:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    if (acquire_view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        acquire_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        gps_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

also, in `onProviderEnabled` method, and everywhere where you set the visibility of one layout (`acquire_view`/`gps_view`), you should also set for the other as well.

Comment: .. hrm first a fc because i forgot to change the type in my class from TableLayout to LinearLayout ... now a fc because ... ? gah i copy pasted your code ... unfortunately i only sort of know how to use the debugger.

Comment: ah thats great! i was trying to do that earlier because i knew it was inefficient to do it repeatedly, but i got sidetracked trying to fix this. and i didnt quite know the right code ... now the debugger seems to be telling me that the linearlayout within gps_layout needs a width, which it wouldn't seem to since it has a weight ...

Comment: ok, awesome your code worked and its centered now but i had to add `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to both of the inner linearlayouts. i thought weight took care of width? any ideas? still curious as to why my phone found objection to the centering to begin with.

Comment: I'm really glad, that you've made it! Please let me know how it goes on